# Как сделать PyQt6 findChildren без self? Или где добыть self для findChildren?

Tags: python, ооп, qt-designer, pyqt6, findchildren

Есть программа с *GUI* на *PyQt6*.

*Gui* делал в *Qt Designer*, потом пропустил через ***`pyuic6`*** с аргументом **`-o`**.

В нарисованном *gui* есть много `QLineEdit`'ов.
Хочу обойти их все в цикле по массиву.

Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui import Ui_MainWindow

def button_clicked():
    # Код кнопки, который должен пройти по всем qlineedit'ам и взять их text()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(button_clicked)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

# в ui там все стандартно, код сгенерирован в qtdesigner`e 
# и содержит в себе кучу lineedit'ов + 1 кнопку pushbutton.
```

Для "Кода кнопки" нашел вот такую конфигурацию:

```
items = [lineEdit for lineEdit in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)]
```

Однако у меня возникла проблема с пониманием того откуда мне взять `self.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

**main.py**

```
import sys

#from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit

from ui_q1451865 import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        # Код кнопки, который должен пройти по всем qlineedit'ам и взять их text()
        items = [lineEdit for lineEdit in self.findChildren(QLineEdit)]
        
        for item in items:
            print(f'{item.objectName()} ----> `{item.text()}`')  
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**ui_q1451865.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(240, 320)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 240, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, сработало! Я подозревал что надо что то переделать, но чего то забуксовал чего и как =)

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 пожалуйста.